# Other ways to use jQuery(html, [ownerdocument | props])?

Tags: jquery

With jquery, besides using the `$(selector)` syntax, [there is also](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) a syntax that is shown for usage as `$("<p>someHTML</p>")`. Now, the only samples of this usage I can find are with `appendTo`.

I'm sure there are other great uses of this feature, but I can't seem to find any documentation on it, or examples of implementation.

It doesn't seem like I can run .find() over it however, but perhaps I set something up incorrectly in my trying it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to wrap html into a JQuery object for further usage. Very handy.
And yes, you can run `find` over it.

```
$("<div><p>First</p><p>Second</p></div>").find("p").each(function(i) {
    alert((i + 1) + " - " + $(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Just to mention. This can potentially avoid unnecessary complexity. Instead of performing a lot of DOM operations over the whole document, you do them at small fragments, and then append the whole thing at once (no I'm not pointing to any flawed micro-benchmarks).

Comment: Now I was reading the doc and it said something about using the js native functions for navigation such as innerHTML, does this mean it creates a hidden container somewhere and operates out of that?

Comment: Internally it must create a DOM Tree from your String somehow. From [the official docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/): "If the HTML is more complex than a single tag without attributes [...] the actual creation of the elements is handled by the browser's innerHTML mechanism. In most cases, jQuery creates a new <div> element and sets the innerHTML property of the element to the HTML snippet that was passed in. When the parameter has a single tag, such as $('<img />') or $('<a></a>'), jQuery creates the element using the native JavaScript createElement() function."